# UISearchDisplayController doesn't fire didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UISearchDisplayController` in it. I have it showing the search results tableview, but clicking any cells never fires `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"did select row");
}
```

I've seen these relevant questions:

- [Why won't my UISearchDisplayController fire the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824202/why-wont-my-uisearchdisplaycontroller-fire-the-didselectrowatindexpath-method)
- [didSelectRowAtIndexPath does not work when uitableview datasource is filtered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280820/didselectrowatindexpath-does-not-work-when-uitableview-datasource-is-filtered)

but I'm not making the same mistake. The view controller implements `UITableViewDelegate` and `UISearchDisplayDelegate`. The `UISearchDisplayController` delegate and searchResultDelegate are hooked up to the view controller in the storyboard. But just to be sure I did the following in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self; 
self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
```

I've even tried:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.delegate = self;
```

The searchResultsTableView is the only `UITableView` in this view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you show in your question is didDeselect, not didSelect. So, if that's what you actually have in your code, that's the problem.

Comment: Huh. Look at that. Thanks.

Comment: Still nope. `#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 NSLog(@"did select");
}`

Comment: @dysfunction, do you get the blue selection color showing when you tap on a cell?

Comment: No, I only get that if I tap and hold (which also does not trigger didSelectRowAtIndexPath).

Comment: @dysfunction, that's certainly not standard behavior. Have you added any gesture recognizer, or done anything else that would make your table view non-standard?

Comment: THAT was it- I had a tap gesture recognizer that was supposed to be hooked up to a view underneath the searchdisplaycontroller, but was accidentally also hooked up to the view controller's root view.